# Active Directory groups

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I am trying to get a list of security groups in AD but I am not having much luck.
When I check Active Directory Users and Computers MMC, I see:

```
blah.blah.com (top)
Group 1
  Group1_1
  Group1_2
    Group1_2_1
Group2
```

and so on.
What I need is all security groups in Group1_2_1
I tried using DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher using "(&(objectClass=group))" as search filter but I get things I can't even find in Active Directory Users and Computers MMC.

This is what I have in C# code:

```
        // Binding path. 
        string strPath = "LDAP://<domain_name>.ABC.DEF.COM";

        // Binding object. 
        DirectoryEntry objADAM = default(DirectoryEntry);
        // Group Results. 
        DirectoryEntry objGroupEntry = default(DirectoryEntry);
        // Search object. 
        DirectorySearcher objSearchADAM = default(DirectorySearcher);
        // Results collection. 
        SearchResultCollection objSearchResults = default(SearchResultCollection);
        // Construct the binding string. 
        List<string> result = new List<string>();            

        // Get the AD LDS object. 
        try
        {
            objADAM = new DirectoryEntry(strPath);
            objADAM.RefreshCache();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        // Get search object, specify filter and scope, 
        // perform search. 
        try
        {
            objSearchADAM = new DirectorySearcher(objADAM);
            objSearchADAM.Filter = "Group1_2_1 (groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)";
            //objSearchADAM.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(OU=Group1_2)(OU=Group1_2_1))";
            objSearchADAM.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            objSearchResults = objSearchADAM.FindAll();
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
Setting your base to:
Group1_2_1
(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)

for [some more examples.](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches)
-jim

Comment: Thank you Jim. I tried it and still get a count of 0 for search result. I edited the original to show the code I have.

Comment: Sorry, I can not test any c# code at the moment. I would suggest you perform your search from a LDAP Browser and get it to work the way you want. Then move to code.

Comment: This worked:  I had to use 
LDAP://<domain_name>.ABC.DCE.COM/OU=Group1_1,OU=Group1_1_2,DC=<domain_name>,DC=ABC,DC=DEF,DC=COM

as the path string for DirectoryEntry (i.e. strPath variable in my code) and then just use (objectcategory=group) as search filter. Replacing "objectcategory=group" with your string also works.

Answer (score -1):

If this is for a single user security groups only then below is the one liner PowerShell script

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity >samaccount< | Where-Object {$_.distinguishedname -notcontains "config"}| Where-Object {$_.GroupCategory -notmatch "distribution"} | select name
```

This will first get the complete membership of a user -> then remove the membership for the 'config' groups -> then filter out distribution groups -> lastly it will give you only the names of the security groups.

Regards,
Avisekh